# Webcam software

Tags: 12.04, webcam

I am keen to use my web cam but can not find any suitable software to facilitate this, could someone please suggest any other applications?

I have tried the software site associated with the Ubuntu Software Center but alas my web cam program still eludes me....HELP

Comment: What is the make and model of your webcam?

Answer (score 6):

I use "cheese webcam booth"  To install, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install cheese
```

Or you can instal it, by clicking [**Cheese** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/cheese/)